# How does this PSD "work"?

Tags: image-editing, psd

I have [a CMYK PSD](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_yBl-184usmZ1JuTzhDWkFDY1E/view?usp=sharing). When I open it in Photoshop seems to have two layers (from front to back):

- A monkey character with a transparent background
- A white background

Yet for some reason, I cannot export the character layer with PSDParse, which extracts PNG layers from PSDs. What format is this character layer in, if it has transparency, but isn't a PNG?

And how can I extract it?

Answer (score 0):

PSD stands for Photoshop Document and it's the default Photoshop file format. It allows us to save the original document status including the layers and open it later to continue the editing. 
The monkey character can be saved as PNG using File > Save As and choosing PNG as the format. If the intention is to preserve the transparency of the layer, then the white background layer should be deleted or hidden (clicking on the eye on the left of the layer) before saving.